# How do I get the "true" root cause of an error in Elasticsearch.NET / NEST?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch.net

I'm doing some custom error handling/logging with Elasticsearch in a .NET environment using Elasticsearch.NET. Given an `IResponse` object, I'm trying to arrive at the best strategy for plucking out a short, succinct, and useful "root cause" message. I originally arrived at this, which works great when we come across indexing errors specifically:

```cs
shortMsg = response.ServerError?.Error?.RootCause?.FirstOrDefault()?.Reason;
```

But I recently ran into a query-time error where the above gave me this:

```
"failed to create query: { ... }"
```

(Details left out, but it effectively dumped the entire query.)

Since that isn't particularly useful, I spent a little time traversing the `response` to see what else is available. `response.ServerError.Error.Reason`, for example, returns `"all shards failed"` - also not particularly useful. `response.DebugInformation` is much bigger than what I'd like for this particular purpose, but I did find the needle in the haystack I was looking for toward end of it:

```
"Can't parse boolean value [True], expected [true] or [false]"
```

That's perfect, and to avoid parsing it out of `DebugInfomation` I also managed to find it here:

```cs
response.ServerError.Error.Metadata.FailedShards.First().Reason.CausedBy.Reason
```

So at this point I've arrived at this strategy to get my `shortMsg`:

```cs
shortMsg =
    response.ServerError?.Error?.Metadata?.FailedShards?.FirstOrDefault()?.Reason?.CausedBy?.Reason ??
    response.ServerError?.Error?.RootCause?.FirstOrDefault()?.Reason;
```

My concern with this is that it might be naive to assume that if something exists along the first path, it'll *always* be "better" than the second. A better understanding of the response structure itself might be key to arriving at the best strategy here.

Any suggestions on improving this?